# Tab index with bootstrap pop up modal menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page how can i specify tab index for bootstrap popup modal  and main differently .

If popup is open table index should be available for  popup modal only.
But when i click on last element of popup modal tab transfer control to main page.

```
 <a href="#">first element</a>
 .
 .
 ...
<a href="#" >last element in popup</a>
```

***when i press tab on last a it should transfer focus to first element instead of transferring to main page content***

Comment: Bootstrap modal will have restriction of tab index inside modal by default. Check out the example here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. You are using some other modal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add id to select in dom

```
 <a href="#" id="first">first element</a>
 .
 .
 ...
<a href="#" id="last" >last element in popup</a>
```

Check if event raised by last a is tab then set focus to first element

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('last').onkeydown = function(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    document.getElementById('first').focus();

                }
            }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you mean when you press tab from the last element and the modal closes, then try adding these inside the modal parameters. 
**( make sure your modal contains a close button, otherwise you will not be able to close the modal as the modal will not close on a input from the "esc" button or a click outside the modal body.)**

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

but if you want to close the modal by clicking out of the modal then use only

```
data-keyboard="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like below

```
$('#myModal').keydown(function(e){
 if($('#last').is(":focus") && (e.which || e.keyCode) == 9){
e.preventDefault();
$('#first').focus();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following:

```
private tabKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let parentModal = $(document).find('.modal');
        //List of html elements which can be focused by tabbing.
        let focusableElementsArrayString = 'a[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, [tabindex="0"]';
        let focusableElementsInModal = parentModal.find(focusableElementsArrayString);
        let numberOfElements = focusableElementsInModal.length;
        let firstTabElement = focusableElementsInModal[0];
        let lastTabElement = focusableElementsInModal[numberOfElements - 1];
        // Check for Shift + Tab
        if (event.keyCode === 9 && event.shiftKey) {
            if (document.activeElement === firstTabElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                lastTabElement.focus();
            } // Check for Tab
        } else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
            if (document.activeElement === lastTabElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                firstTabElement.focus();
            }
        }
    }
```